# Refreshing nested iframe from separate window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe called "mainframe" you click a link inside the iframe, and it uses javascript to open a small popup window. I have a form inside this popup-window that submits data to be displayed in the iframe. (its a comment feature) I want there to be a way that when the user clicks "submit" the popup window closes, and the iframe refreshes. How to do this?

Comment: you can check this link: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/comment-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

Comment: that would be a great solution if I had thought of this problem before having the whole site built :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the popup window, you can use the `opener` property to get to the parent window.  From there, you can use the `frames` collection to get to your iframe...

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('btnSubmit').onclick = function() {
    opener.frames[0].location.reload(true);
    self.close();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you need some kind of delay, you can setup a function in the parent window...

```
function refreshIframe() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    frames[0].location.reload(true);
  }, 1000);
}
```

And invoke it from the popup...

```
opener.refreshIframe();
self.close();
```

Comment: that will work real well, except I have little experience with javascript, would you please elaborate a little more? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might seem as a stupid answer but lets throw a dart with closed eyes.
So to the point u can definitely do this with help of jquery in case of div not sure about frame but should work according to me

Comment: thanks, but I would have to rebuild my whole site structure to accomplish this

Comment: Well u can use frame as well and u should have tried testing it but YEA it worked. =.=

Comment: oh okay, well I didnt vote you down, just for the record haha

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to refresh your iframe:
document.getElementById("mainframe").contentDocument.location.reload(true);